"Sender Not Authenticated" Warning in Gmail for Emails Sent from Netlify Server Though Private Domain Email
I'm encountering an issue where emails sent from my Netlify server through Netlify cron-job show a "Sender not authenticated" warning in Gmail. The emails are being sent successfully, but this warning appears when I divert my private domain emails to my Gmail account through POP3. Interestingly, when I send emails directly to a Gmail address, this warning does not appear.
Setup:
Email Service: Using nodemailer to send emails.
SMTP Configuration: Configured to use a private domain email ID.
DNS Records: SPF, DMARC, and DKIM are correctly configured.
email.js(SMTP)
const sendEmail = async (options) => {
   try {
       const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
           host: 'shared66.accountservergroup.com',
           port: 587,
           secure: false,
           auth: {
               user: process.env.EMAIL_USERNAME,
               pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD
           }
       });

       const mailOptions = {
           from: `Movya Infotech <${process.env.EMAIL_USERNAME}>`,
           to: options.email,
           subject: options.subject,
           text: options.message,
       };

       if (options.fileName && options.filePath) {
           mailOptions.attachments = [{
               filename: options.fileName,
               path: options.filePath
           }];
       }

       await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
   } catch (error) {
       console.error("Error sending email:", error);
       throw error;
   }
}

module.exports = sendEmail;

Problem:

The "Sender not authenticated" warning appears in Gmail when emails are diverted from my private domain to Gmail via POP3.
This warning does not appear when emails are sent directly to a Gmail address.

Questions:

Could there be a configuration issue specific to how emails are diverted to Gmail via POP3 that's causing this warning?
Are there additional settings or configurations I should check or implement to prevent this warning?

Additional Information:

The SMTP is configured to use a private domain email ID.
SPF, DMARC, and DKIM records are verified and correctly set up.

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!
Github Link

Project: https://github.com/patoliyabhi7/GreetingsEmailCronJob
Direct Link to Netlify Cronjob file:
https://github.com/patoliyabhi7/GreetingsEmailCronJob/blob/main/netlify/functions/cron-job.js

Warning Image
